# Apache POI to read excel file with many worksheets and write single sheet to new file

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am using Apache POI to read an xlsx file that has many worksheets in it.
I want to write out the contents to a new xlsx file, but I only want one selected worksheet from the original input.

The example I have (code below) reads the file fine, but it writes out all worksheets to the file. I need to know what to do to write only one of the sheets. 
Can I do that?

```
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class ExcelTest {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {  

    try
    {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("FileLotOfSheets.xlsx"));
        //Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

        //Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
       // XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);

        file.close();

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("FileOnlyOneSheetFromLots.xlsx");
        workbook.write(out);
        out.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: And you haven't tried anything than this? Really?

Comment: Your code doesn't manipulate the `XSSFWorkbook` at all.  Think about what needs to be done to the `XSSFWorkbook` to remove all sheets but the desired sheet.

Comment: Thank you rgettman.  I am new to Java and apologize for the basic nature of my questions. Your suggestion was most helpful.

Comment: I added this before closing file:          String sheetName = "mySheet";
        for(int i=workbook.getNumberOfSheets()-1;i>=0;i--){
            XSSFSheet tmpSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);
            if(!tmpSheet.getSheetName().equals(sheetName)){
                workbook.removeSheetAt(i);
            }
        }                now only question is it more efficient to keep only one I want instead of delete? I'll have to try it.

Comment: try this [link](http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/06/19/readingwriting-excel-files-in-java-poi-tutorial/) it will help you for sure to start with POI and figure out the answer to your problem by yourself

Comment: Thank you, A B. Very useful link for what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File(
                "FileLotOfSheets.xlsx"));
        // Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);

        /* ------------------------------------------------------------ 
         * As per suggestion from rgettman to remove all but desired sheet,
         * added the following lines to get rid of the unwanted sheets.
         * Result is workbook with only the sheet I want.
         * ------------------------------------------------------------- */
        String sheetName = "mySheet";
        for (int i = workbook.getNumberOfSheets() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            XSSFSheet tmpSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(i);
            if (!tmpSheet.getSheetName().equals(sheetName)) {
                workbook.removeSheetAt(i);
            }
        }
        /*----------------------------------------------------------------*/

        file.close();

        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(
                "FileOnlyOneSheetFromLots.xlsx");
        workbook.write(out);
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following version of `main`

```
 public static void main( String [] args ) {
  try {

    InputStream input = POIExample.class.getResourceAsStream( "qa.xls" );
    POIFSFileSystem fs = new POIFSFileSystem( input );
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(fs);


    for (int i = 0; i < wb.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
        HSSFSheet sheet = wb.getSheetAt(i);

        // Do your stuff        
    }

} catch ( IOException ex ) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
}
```